# как создать объект из класса на чистом js

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию добавления картинки на сайт. Для этого был создан класс для картинки:

```js
class Picture_post{
  constructor(picture_id, picture_url, likes_count, dislikes_count){
    this.picture_id = picture_id;
    this.picture_url = picture_url;
    this.likes_count = likes_count;
    this.dislikes_count = dislikes_count;
  }
}
```

На сайте уже присутствуют дефолтные блоки с картинками, для каждой картинки был созлан вручную объект, например `let pic1 = new Picture_post("pic1","url('Img/pic1.png')","3","0");` создан массив `var pictures_array = []` и каждый объект был запихнут в этот массив методом `pictures_array.push(pic1);`.
Также была создана коллекция классов `let image_block = document.getElementsByClassName("image-block");`. Суть в том, что скрипт считает количество блоков с картинками и запихивает их в коллекцию `image-block` потом он каждому блоку присваивает значения из массива объектов `pictures_array`

На сайте присутствует форма для загрузки картинки:

```html
<form id="adding-picture-form" method="post">
  <button id="submit-picture-uploading-button" type="button" name="submit-picture-uploading-button"></button>
  <label id="adding-picture-label" for="adding-picture-input">Add your Picture</label>
  <input id="adding-picture-input" name="adding-picture-input" type="file" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

Сам input был скрыт от глаз юзера, а открытие диалогового (для загрузки картинки) окна происходит через клик на label.
На данный момент на форме висят такие функции:

```js
let adding_picture_label = document.getElementById("adding-picture-label");
let adding_picture_input = document.getElementById("adding-picture-input");
let submit_picture_uploading_button = document.getElementById("submit-picture-uploading-button");

adding_picture_input.addEventListener('change',()=>{
   let picture = adding_picture_input.files[0];
   if(picture){
     adding_picture_label.innerHTML = picture.name;
     return picture;
   }
   else{
     adding_picture_label.innerHTML = 'Add your Picture';
     return picture;
   }
 },false);

submit_picture_uploading_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let picture = adding_picture_input.files[0];
   if(picture){
     console.log(picture);
   }
   else{
     adding_picture_label.innerHTML = 'Upload picture first';
   }
  },false);
```

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы при клике на кнопку submit скрипт создавал новый объект картинки из моего класса,  `picture_url` присваивал значение  `adding_picture_input.files[0]` `likes_count` и `dislikes_count` было по нулям. Проблема в том, что я не знаю каким образом сделать создание нового объекта "универсальным". Что бы можно было прописать что-то типо `let pic[pictures_array.length] = new Picture_post("pic"[pictures_array.length],"url('Img/adding_picture_input.files[0]')","0","0");` где место переменной `pictures_array.length` прописывалась уже готовенькая циферка и на выходе получалось, к примеру `let pic8 = new Picture_post("pic8","url('Img/pic8.png')","0","0");` и это добро сохранялось в массиве `pictures_array` для дальнейшей работы.
Благодарю за любую помощь.

Comment: Для чего вообще этот велосипед, при том что DOM-объекты расширяемы? Какова общая цель, идея такой системы?

Comment: Это не критика, а попытка понять причину избыточного усложнения (так это выглядит на данный момент). Возможно, подскажу более рациональный вариант.

Comment: Задание на курсы. Сделать галерею с картинками и возможность добавлять туда новые картинки. Жс знаю плохо поэтому додумалась пока что только до такого варианта реализации.

Comment: А добавление картинок должно быть только локально, без отправки на сервер? (просто наличие формы с фактической отправкой слегка противоречит тексту в последнем абзаце, о создании картинки в документе при сабмите). Вообще класс на самом деле не нужен, достаточно простого объекта - его можно хранить как в массиве, так и в свойстве DOM-объекта (это сильно упростит решение).

Comment: Добавление только локально. Насколько я поняла это должно происходить каким то магическом образом через localStorage. Поскольку в тз указано, что картинки должны сохранятся на сайте после обновления страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем Вам переменные `pic1`, `pic2` и так далее?

```
var pictures_array = [];
...
var i = pictures_array.length;

...

i++;
pictures_array.push(new Picture_post("pic" + i, "url('Img/pic" + i + ".png')", 0, 0);
```

Comment: они нужны что бы потом из содержимого этих объектов на страницу выводились количество лайков/дизлаков, сама картинка в определенный блок.

Comment: @Elysium Они не нужны. Эти объекты находятся в массиве. Оттуда их и берите, чтобы "из содержимого этих объектов на страницу выводились ...".

Comment: спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 1):

Ключевые моменты:

1. Класс без методов и приватных свойств - имеет смысл только если расширять им стандартный DOM-объект (показано в примере). В остальных случаях, для хранения инфы в виде "ключ: значение", будет достаточно простого объекта;
2. Расширяются не только объекты через "наследование", но и их экземпляры. Добавление свойств экземпляру DOM-объекта (элементу) это *абсолютно нормальная* практика, несмотря на то что некоторые ее боятся. Главное - не допускать возможного пересечения имен свойств (в примере используется объектное свойство, структурное хранение это один из вариантов избежания конфликтов);
3. При наличии живой коллекции (от `getElementsByClassName`), массив элементов/экземпляров совершенно не нужен - см. в примере код обновления общего количества картинок. Коллекция обновляется автоматически, поэтому и называется живой. А так как мы расширяем свойствами объекты элементов - всегда можем получить доступ к этим свойствам через коллекцию (например, лайки первого изображения это `imgs[0].myOpts.cntLikes`)

```js
class MyImg extends Image {
  constructor(opts = {}) {
    super(); 
    const { src, classes, ...myOpts } = opts; 
    Object.assign(this, { myOpts }); 
    this.addEventListener('load', 
      ({ target }) => URL.revokeObjectURL(target.src)
    , { once: true }); 
    this.classList.add(...classes); 
    this.src = src; 
  }
}

const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class'), 
      glry = document.querySelector('#gallery'), 
      frm  = document.forms.addPic;
frm.picFile.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.files.length) return; 
  glry.appendChild(new MyImg({
    src: URL.createObjectURL(target.files[0]), 
    classes: ['my-class'], 
    cntLikes: 0,
    cntDislikes: 0
  })); 
  frm.querySelector('.pic-count').textContent = imgs.length; 
  frm.reset(); 
});
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
#gallery { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; align-items: center; }
#gallery .my-class { max-width: 100%; width: 200px; margin: 0 auto 0.5rem auto; }
#add-pic, #add-pic label { display: block; width: 100%; padding: 0.3em 0 0.5em 0; text-align: center; }
#add-pic .choose-file { text-decoration: underline dashed; color: #47e; background: #eee; }
#add-pic input[type="file"] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="gallery"></div>
<form id="add-pic" name="addPic" action="javascript:void(0)">
  <label>Total: <span class="pic-count">0</span> picture(s)</label>
  <label class="choose-file">Add your Picture
    <input name="picFile" type="file" accept="image/*">
  </label>
</form>
```

Возможность ставить лайки/дизлайки, их вывод в галерее, и работа с `localStorage` - не реализованы сознательно, чтобы оставить пространство для доработки решения (т.к. задание учебное, а копипаст ничему не научит). При возникновении трудностей с реализацией этих фич, всегда можно задать новый, более конкретный вопрос :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. По заданию, к сожалению, нельзя использовать вспомогательные библиотеки. Но свойство `URL.createObjectURL` очень сильно помогло.

Comment: @Elysium, В примере нет сторонних библиотек, это чистейшие стандартные JS и DOM.

Comment: Подумала, что `querySelector` это что-то из библиотеки jQuery, извиняюсь)